# How to add onmouseout for tabs so that the tab content won't show up when the mouseout?

Tags: javascript, tabs

I'm trying to add an onmouseout for a tab function and I'm using w3schools tab example, which has an onmouseover and that would show the tabcontent when hovering on tablink, but the content stays in, and an onmouseout would probably solve my question, the only problem is that I have no idea how to get around that. Thanks!

Example

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
      // Declare all variables
      var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    
      // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
      tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
      for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    
      // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
      tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
      for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
    
      // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
      document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
      evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
```

```html
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onmouseover="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onmouseover="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onmouseover="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
    </div>
    
    <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>London</h3>
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Paris</h3>
      <p>Paris is the capital city of France.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Tokyo</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital city of Japan.</p>
    </div>
```

see how it works [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_hover_tabs)

Comment: Looks like a simple typo, IDs can't have spaces (`London2` instead of `London 2`) and you don't have divs for Paris and Tokyo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add mouseout listener to your tab `div`

```
const tabs = document.querySelector('.tab');

tabs.addEventListener("mouseout", function( event ) {    
      // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
      const tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");

      for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "block";
      }
 }, false)
```

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
      // Declare all variables
      var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    
      // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
      tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
      for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    
      // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
      tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
      for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
    
      // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
      document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
      evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
 }
 
 const tabs = document.querySelector('.tab');
 
 tabs.addEventListener("mouseout", function( event ) {    
  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  const tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");

  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "block";
  }
 }, false)
```

```html
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onmouseover="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onmouseover="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onmouseover="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
    </div>
    
    <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>London</h3>
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Paris</h3>
      <p>Paris is the capital city of France.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Tokyo</h3>
      <p>Tokyo is the capital city of Japan.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Changing this the style to this solve is what I was looking for. 
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
      }
 }, false)